`\IfSubStr` in a tikz style
I am trying to create a pic that accepts an argument which encodes what items in the pic should be drawn in a different color. The problem, however, seems not to be about the pic; therefore, I've come up with the MNWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xstring}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{t/.style={
        s/.style={fill=\IfSubStr{##1}{#1}{black}{}}
    }}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[t={a,b}]
        \node[s={a}] {};
        \node[s={b}] {};
        \node[s={c}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

apparently, tikz does not like the IfSubStr in the filling. How can I make the fill property depend on parameters?

What do you expect shpuld happen? Why don't you write \node[col1] ... and define e.g. col1/.style={fill=orange!20}, etc. ?

@Bubaya So basically the argument can take one value of a set of values and some pgfkeys-keys shall be set depending on which value the argument has? Probably the possible values of the argument can denote different pgfkeys-styles for setting the keys accordingly?

@UlrichDiez Yes, exactly. Essentially, I pass a list of items (corresponding to the nodes) to the pic, and all the nodes corresponding to these items should be highlighted.

The main problem is, you cannot have code like \IfSubStr in a style s or in a value-key fill.
I suggest to turn s itself into a key that processes code and calls \tikzset for setting fill, but I doubt that \IfSubStr is really what you want:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xstring}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{t/.style={
        s/.code={\IfSubStr{#1}{##1}{\tikzset{fill=green}}{\tikzset{fill=red}}}
    }}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[t={a,b}]
        \node[s={a,}] at (0,0) {`a,' is in `a,b'};
        \node[s={,}] at (0,1) {`,' is in `a,b'};
        \node[s={,b}] at (0,2) {`,b' is in `a,b'};
        \node[s={a,b}] at (0,3) {`a,b' is in `a,b'};
        \node[s={a}] at (0,4) {`a' is in `a,b'};
        \node[s={b}] at (0,5) {`b' is in `a,b'};
        \node[s={c}] at (0,6) {`c' is not in `a,b'};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Expl3's package l3clist provides infrastructure for checking items of comma-lists:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \tikzset{t/.style={
        s/.code={\clist_if_in:nnTF{#1}{##1}{\tikzset{fill=green}}{\tikzset{fill=red}}}
    }}
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \begin{tikzpicture}[t={a,b}]
        \node[s={a,}] at (0,0) {`a,' is not an element of the list `a,b'};
        \node[s={,}] at (0,1) {`,' is not an element of the list `a,b'};
        \node[s={,b}] at (0,2) {`,b' is not an element of the list `a,b'};
        \node[s={a,b}] at (0,3) {`a,b' is not an element of the list `a,b'};
        \node[s={a}] at (0,4) {`a' is an element of the list `a,b'};
        \node[s={b}] at (0,5) {`b' is an element of the list `a,b'};
        \node[s={c}] at (0,6) {`c' is not an element of the list `a,b'};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

You can also implement mapping of fill-colors:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__mymodule_scratch_tl
\cs_new:Nn \__mymodule_map_kvpair:Nnnn {\tl_put_right:Nn #1 {{#3}{\tikzset{#2#4}}}}
\cs_new:Nn \__mymodule_i_iii_ii:nnn {#1{#3}{#2}}
\cs_new:Nn \__mymodule_tl_braces:nn {#1 {{#2}}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mymodule_tl_braces:nn { nV }
\tikzset{
  t/.code~2~args={
    \group_begin:
    \tl_set:Nn  \l__mymodule_scratch_tl { \tl_clear:N \l__mymodule_scratch_tl }
    \clist_map_tokens:nn {#1} {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mymodule_scratch_tl {\__mymodule_map_kvpair:Nnnn \l__mymodule_scratch_tl {fill=} }
      \__mymodule_i_iii_ii:nnn { \tl_map_tokens:nn }  { \__mymodule_tl_braces:nn {  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mymodule_scratch_tl }  }
    }
    \tl_use:N \l__mymodule_scratch_tl
    \__mymodule_tl_braces:nV {\tl_set:Nn\l__mymodule_scratch_tl} \l__mymodule_scratch_tl
    \tl_put_left:Nn \l__mymodule_scratch_tl { \str_case:nnF {##1} }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mymodule_scratch_tl {\tikzset{fill=#2} }
    \__mymodule_tl_braces:nV {\tl_set:Nn\l__mymodule_scratch_tl} \l__mymodule_scratch_tl
    \tl_put_left:Nn \l__mymodule_scratch_tl { s/.code= }
    \__mymodule_tl_braces:nV {\tl_set:Nn\l__mymodule_scratch_tl} \l__mymodule_scratch_tl
    \tl_put_left:Nn \l__mymodule_scratch_tl {\group_end: \tikzset }
    \tl_use:N \l__mymodule_scratch_tl
  },
  t={{a}{cyan},{c}{green}}{none},
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[s={a,}] at (0,0) {`a,' is not mapped, thus fill=none is used.};
        \node[s={,}] at (0,1) {`,' is not mapped, thus fill=none is used.};
        \node[s={,b}] at (0,2) {`,b' is not mapped, thus fill=none is used.};
        \node[s={a,b}] at (0,3) {`a,b' is not mapped, thus fill=none is used.};
        \node[s={a}] at (0,4) {`a' is mapped to fill=cyan.};
        \node[s={b}] at (0,5) {`b'  is not mapped, thus fill=none is used.};
        \node[s={c}] at (0,6) {`c' is mapped to fill=green.};
    \end{tikzpicture}

   \vfill

    \begin{tikzpicture}[t={{a}{green},{b}{blue}}{none}]
        \node[s={a,}] at (0,0) {`a,' is not mapped, thus fill=none is used.};
        \node[s={,}] at (0,1) {`,' is not mapped, thus fill=none is used.};
        \node[s={,b}] at (0,2) {`,b' is not mapped, thus fill=none is used.};
        \node[s={a,b}] at (0,3) {`a,b' is not mapped, thus fill=none is used.};
        \node[s={a}] at (0,4) {`a' is mapped to fill=green.};
        \node[s={b}] at (0,5) {`b' is mapped to fill=blue.};
        \node[s={c}] at (0,6) {`c' is not mapped, thus fill=none is used.};
    \end{tikzpicture}

   \vfill

    \begin{tikzpicture}[t={{a}{orange},{b}{green},{c}{cyan}}{red}]
        \node[s={a,}] at (0,0) {`a,' is not mapped, thus fill=red is used.};
        \node[s={,}] at (0,1) {`,' is not mapped, thus fill=red is used.};
        \node[s={,b}] at (0,2) {`,b' is not mapped, thus fill=red is used.};
        \node[s={a,b}] at (0,3) {`a,b' is not mapped, thus fill=red is used.};
        \node[s={a}] at (0,4) {`a' is mapped to fill=orange.};
        \node[s={b}] at (0,5) {`b' is mapped to fill=green.};
        \node[s={c}] at (0,6) {`c' is mapped to fill=cyan.};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \vfill    
\end{document}

Probably you prefer choice-keys:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  /utils/exec=\newcommand*\codephrase{.code},
  s/.is choice,
  s/.unknown/.code={\tikzset{fill=none}},
  t/MyForbiddenPath/.unknown/.code={%
    \tikzset{s/\ifx\pgfkeyscurrentname\codephrase .unknown\else\pgfkeyscurrentname\fi/.code={\tikzset{fill=#1}}}%
  },
  t/.code={\tikzset{t/MyForbiddenPath/.cd, #1}}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[t={a=orange,b=green,c=cyan,.unknown=red}]
        \node[s=a] at (0,0) {`a' is mapped to fill=orange.};
        \node[s=b] at (0,1) {`b' is mapped to fill=green.};
        \node[s=c] at (0,2) {`c' is mapped to fill=cyan.};
        \node[s=d] at (0,3) {`d' is not mapped, thus mapping to default .unknown=red.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

But choice-keys behave weird when the choice-value (erroneously) contains a comma.
In the example, the t-key is used for defining the choice-sub-keys for s.
The problem is, you cannot use this outside a local scope like a tikzpicture-environment and you cannot nest local scopes with calls to the t-key as already defined choice-sub-keys will not be overridden.

Instead of using \tikzset it would be more correct to use \pgfkeysalso in a .style-replacement. Also note that you have a systematic error in the naming of your L3 variables and functions. A package-internal variable should start with the scope and then have two consecutive underscores (e.g., \l__mymodule_scratch_tl), and an internal function should start with two underscores (e.g., \__mymodule_tl_braces:nn).

@Skillmon Thanks for pointing out proper naming of things in expl3. Regarding \pgfkeysalso versus \tikzset I am a bit confused about "more correct": pgfmanual.pdf says: With \pgfkeysalso the default path is not modified. With \tikzset the default path is set to /tikz. While I am not sure whether using the path /tikz for defining one's own things really is good practise it seems the questioner wished things to be placed into the path /tikz for some reason. So I used \tikzset to ensure usage of this path.

Yes, but the ultimate goal of the question (as I understand it), is to replace .style with something that evaluates things and then does the same as a .style, and a .style is defined as .code={\pgfkeysalso{#1}}.

You could do something like the following, but it would be better if you could explain what you really try to do as there might be a better solution to this.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, xstring}

\colorlet{mycolor}{black}
\def\mycolorlist{}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        t/.code={\def\mycolorlist{#1}},
        s/.code={
            \IfSubStr{\mycolorlist}{#1}{
                \colorlet{mycolor}{black}
            }{
                \colorlet{mycolor}{red}
            }
            \tikzset{fill=mycolor}
        }
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[t={a,b}]
        \node[s={a}] at (0,0) {};
        \node[s={b}] at (1,0) {};
        \node[s={c}] at (2,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



See my edit for what I am after.
